# Powershell output to HTML

Tags: powershell

Im trying to pull the "info" property of a secure group and convert to html but in the result i also get @{info= my info}

There are many other things that i pull up but here is where im having issues

```
$user = $env:username
$OfficeLocations = @("San Antonio Sales","Oregon Sales","Phoenix Sales")
$OfficeAddress = foreach($OfficeLocation in $OfficeLocations)
{
    Get-ADGroup -Identity $OfficeLocation -Properties * | Select-Object info
}
$objGroup = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user  | Select-Object name

 if ($objGroup.name -contains "San Antonio Sales") 
 {
    $Address = $OfficeAddress[0]
 }
 elseif ($objGroup.name -contains "Oregon Sales") 
 {
     $Address = $OfficeAddress[1]
 }
 elseif ($objGroup.name -contains "Phoenix Sales")
 {
     $Address = $OfficeAddress[2]
 }

#then i replace a template
(get-content .\directory.html) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "%%ADDRESS%%", $Address} | set-content $fullOutputPath
```

when opening the file it outputs the address but leaves the:

**@{info=** 123 main street, suite#123, the city, the state, zip **}** (example)

How can i clear the @{info= }?

Thanks in advance for any comment and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$Address` is an Address object, not just a string.  What you need is a string representation of that object.  The upside is that you can format your string any way you want.

Try something like this near the bottom.  Use the actual property names if you know them.

```
$AddressString = "$($Address.Str1), $($Address.Str2), $($Address.city), $($Address.state)"
(get-content .\directory.html) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "%%ADDRESS%%", $AddressString} | set-content $fullOutputPath
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what i was looking and is what solved my issue.
I just needed to add:  $Address = $($Address.info) and it did the trick.

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative technique for replacing variables in HTML templates (or any text files, really), is to use `Invoke-Expression`.

Let's say you have a simple template to display some server details:

```
<html>
<head><title>Details for $serverName</title></head>
<body>
<b>Name: </b>$serverName<br/>
<b>OS Version: </b>$osVersion<br/>
<b>Serial Number: </b>$serialNumber<br/>
<b>InstallDate: </b>$installDate<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

The 'trick' is to specify the variables to be replaced using standard PowerShell name/format and not any other common standard (e.g. `%%variable%%`, `{{variable}},` etc).

You can update the variables and output a customised HTML page like this:

```
$osDetails = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem

$serverName = $osDetails.CSName
$osVersion = $osDetails.Caption
$installDate = $osDetails.InstallDate
$serialNumber = $osDetails.SerialNumber

$template = (Get-Content '.\server_template.html' -Raw)

Invoke-Expression "@`"`r`n$template`r`n`"@" |
    Set-Content -Path ".\$serverName`_details.html"
```

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Details for Server1</title></head>
<body>
<b>Name: </b>Server1<br/>
<b>OS Version: </b>Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise<br/>
<b>Serial Number: </b>12345-12345-12345-12345<br/>
<b>InstallDate: </b>01/01/2018 09:00:00<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

While `Invoke-Command` can be dangerous sometimes, here it is very useful as it can replace multiple variables in one short command.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, now i now i can use the invoke-expression to do the same. This does convert the information to HTML but in this particular case i still had issues with the address and as the comment above mentioned. I needed to convert the object "info" to a string.
 $strAddress = $($strAddress.info)

Thanks.