# Windows Service Status as a Web Page

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

I have got a need to check ISS Service status whether running or stopped. So I am using

```
Get-Service AppHostSVC,FTPSVC,IISAdmin,MSFTPSVC,W3SVC,WAS,WMSVC
```

I need to run this for command for every 5 minutes, so I am using this script

```
Import-Module TaskScheduler $task = New-Task
$task.Settings.Hidden = $true
Add-TaskAction -Task $task -Path C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe –Arguments “Get-Service AppHostSVC,FTPSVC,IISAdmin,MSFTPSVC,W3SVC,WAS,WMSVC”
Add-TaskTrigger -Task $task -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5)
Register-ScheduledJob –Name ”Monitor IIS Service” -Task $task
```

I need to show the status of those services as a Web page in c:\IISServiceChecker.html which will be refreshed every 5 minutes. This part I am struggling on how to put the status in a web page. Any help would be much appreciated
Thank you

Comment: take a look at convertto-html, e.g. Get-Service AppHostSVC,FTPSVC,IISAdmin,MSFTPSVC,W3SVC,WAS,WMSVC | select-object name,status | convertto-html | set-content c:\IISServiceChecker.html -force

Comment: `Get-Service <srvs> | ConvertTo-Html -Property <props> | Out-File <path>` is the first thing that comes to mind. Have you explored the ConvertTo-Html option?

Comment: If you're looking to make a more complex web page (e.g. with custom layout, styling, etc), an alternative to the basic `ConvertTo-Html` is to use a template with `Invoke-Expression`.  Here is a simple example of how to do it: [Powershell output to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769327/9529842).

Comment: Thank you for the response. ConvertTo-Html parameter helped to create the WebPage